# Connecting points in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a collection of points displayed in a graphic:

[alt text http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/874/plc1k1lrqynuyshgrdegvfy.jpg](http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/874/plc1k1lrqynuyshgrdegvfy.jpg)

I'd like to know if there is any command that will connect them automatically along the xx and yy axis. This can be better understood looking at the following picture:
[alt text http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/5926/tr53exnkpeofcuiw40koyks.jpg](http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/5926/tr53exnkpeofcuiw40koyks.jpg)
 (I am not asking how to implement the algorithm myself!).

Thanks

Comment: Connect them in what way ? Every with every ? To make a grid ?

Comment: Good question. I wasn't specific enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of what you are looking for is in the [`ComputationalGeometry` Package](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ComputationalGeometry/tutorial/ComputationalGeometry.html).  In particular, [`ConvexHull`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ComputationalGeometry/ref/ConvexHull.html) will give you the outer points listed in counterclockwise direction.  At which point you can use `Line` to connect them together.  The inner paths are a bit trickier, and I don't think there is an exact match.  But, a [`DelaunayTriangulation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ComputationalGeometry/ref/DelaunayTriangulation.html) comes closest.  It essentially breaks your list of points up into sets of triangles.  I don't know of a built in function that would break it into rectangles, though.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the answer is no, there's no such command.  It would be interesting to write something to do that though, ie, given a list of points, output the corresponding lines.  I guess that would just be a matter of:

For each unique x-coordinate get the list of y-coordinates for points with that x-coordinate and make a line from the min to the max y-coordinate.  Then repeat for the y-coordinates.

If you do that, it would be interesting to post it here as a follow-up.  Or if you want to make that the question, I'm sure you'll get some nice solutions.

Answer (score 4):

I vote for [dreeves' suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808052/connecting-points-in-mathematica/1814579#1814579). It doesn't use a "built-in" function, but it's a one-liner using functional programming and level specifications. An implementation is:

```
gridify[pts : {{_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ} ...}] :=
  Map[Line, GatherBy[pts, #]& /@ {First, Last}, {2}]
```